How to handle length changes due to normalization (NFKC for my use-case)?
Normalization does not always result in a 1-1 mapping of characters. Characters like 'ﬁ' will break into 'fi' and some Japanese/Chinese characters can combine into a single character. I need a way to map offsets between the normalized and original strings. Is there any library or method to solve this issue accurately?
Using approximations by finding surrounding characters which are not affected by the normalization such as English letters and whitespaces helps, but it is not accurate enough.

Please have a look at how to ask.

The fastest, simplest, will-not-fail method is to build your index list at the same time you are building your normalized string. Whatever library you are using should have functions to do one step at a time.

I use the windows API currently, and there is no such option for it. I am considering using the ICU libraries for linux. If there is a better c++ library with the above functionality that would be great.
